# Documented modal not displaying in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The [Javascript documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) from Twitter Bootstrap presents the following example:

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

However, I can't see anything: the Chrome Developer Tools indicate that the enclosing `div` is supposed to occupy 1140px by 0px. I also tried removing the `fade` class, to no avail.

I haven't had trouble, so far, testing other components. I should say that I'm using CDN for testing as follows:

```
<!-- at the end of HEAD -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- at the end of BODY -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">/script>
```

What could be causing this collapse?

Comment: The .modal is hidden by default. What code are you using to open the modal?

Comment: I'm sorry... a few lines down there is a live example where it shows that something like `<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">` and using `id="myModal"` in the `div` that defines the modal should do the trick. Thanks! Feel free to write an answer so that I can check the answer. I get too anxious reading the docs, and thought that "static example" was supposed to do show something! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`.modal` is hidden by default. You need to include a link to open the modal..

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
```